# Grails 3 Spring Security Core: grant access only when user not logged in

Tags: spring-security

I understand I can set @Secured('permitAll') on the controller to allow access, though I want to restrict access to only those who are not logged in and permitAll allows even logged in user to access. I have went through the documentation but I seem to miss it? I want the user/create to only be accessible when there's no user that's logged in. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict code if user doesn't have a role.

```
def userRoleNames = springSecurityService.principal.authorities*.authority
if (userRoleNames == null){...}
```

That is one solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!springSecurityService.loggedIn) { . . . }
```